# "That ain't no small potatoes." Are there any similar, yet vulgar, idioms?

Tags: idioms, slang, idiom-requests, offensive-language

It is said that back in the middle ages, university students from various regions who communicated with one another in Latin came up with this intriguing phrase:

> "*Lingua Latina non verpa canina est*."

There are variations of this phrase, which means, roughly, "The Latin Language isn't a dog's dick."

Meaning there's a pretty steep learning curve when it comes to mastering Latin.

Question:

Can you think of something similar in English? "No small potatoes," yes, but with a bit more thrust?

Comment: To make sure I've understood: you're looking for a vulgar, idiomatic saying that means "English is hard to learn"?

Comment: You could say ''Learning language X is a ball-ache'', meaning learning it is difficult and frustrating.

Comment: What is considered vulgar or offensive and what not can be highly regional.

Comment: What does the metaphor mean?

Comment: How about "Learning Latin is a bitch" ?

Comment: @HollisWilliams: Do you really say that? It would be "balls-ache" where I come from.

Comment: "Small potatoes" means something insignificant, not something easy.

Comment: Yours will *pucker up tighter than a snare drum* when you find out it's *dug in like an Alabama tick* on a *broke dick dog*.

Comment: @TonyK Yes.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ball-ache

Comment: @Mazura I didn't understand a word of that.

Comment: @HollisWilliams - Quotes from *Shawshank Redemption* and *Predator*.

Answer (score 8):

***Piece of piss*** is a vulgar idiom for something very easy to do. It is a vulgar version of "piece of cake".

> (*vulgar, Britain, New Zealand, Australian slang*) Something easy to achieve. - *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piece_of_piss)* 
> *Rollerblading is a piece of piss if you know how to roller-skate.*

It was originally Royal Air Force slang and the first written usage is from 1949, from Eric Partridge's *Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* per *OED* and *[GDoS](https://greensdictofslang.com/sources/5281)*. The negation of the idiom is common also and here is a pun-intended example I've found:

> Design isn't a piece of piss and looking at what goes wrong with toilet facilities is a good way of changing your thinking about UI and UX. - *[medium.com](https://medium.com/@themeansagency/urinals-and-user-experience-what-toilets-teach-you-about-ux-ui-and-bad-design-ae593c13e1ec)*

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of what OP asks?

Comment: @Tim The negation has the right effect. Have you read the whole answer? The OP's examples rely on negation also for the intended meaning.